# Is it possible to clear Safari's cache when my app is uninstalled?

Tags: react-native

People at my startup are losing their minds over this. We use a branch deep-linking intelligent mode configuration, but our app is buggy, so internal users frequently have to uninstall and reinstall. When they hit one of our branch deep links, they get the message from Safari "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid."

Per Branch, this is because of frequent uninstalls/reinstalls and Safari being unsure whether it should launch the app or not.

So what I'm wondering is whether there's a way to force, as part of the uninstall process, the clearing of all cached data from Safari related to our app so that it functions as expected every time.

Uninstalling and reinstalling the app repeatedly.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier, and have the same effect, to do something on reinstallation? If you are able to clear the cache while your app is installed, just do it once on first run.

Comment: That seems like it might work too. It's definitely something we'll have to explore- I just don't know if there's no evidence in the cache of the app being installed whether it will default to the 'is not installed' behavior. Thank you for the comment!